In the photoelectric effect, is the frequency in the work function by any mean a property for the absorptive atom in the cathode?
The work function is given by $E_{w}=h\nu_{c}$. Can we attribute the frequency $\nu_{c}$ to the absorptive atom itself? I mean, removing an electron from an atom result in forming a positive ion with an energy greater than the energy of the original atom by an amount equal to h$\nu_{c}$. According to Planck, the energy of an atom is at least h$\bar{\nu}$ where $\bar{\nu}$ is the frequency of the atomic oscillation, and the energy only increases in quanta, multiple number of h$\bar{\nu}$. That being said, I've concluded that since the atom absorbed an energy equal to h$\nu_{c}$, then its energy before absorption must have been nh$\nu_{c}$ and absorbing that quantum must raise the energy of the atom to (n+1)h$\nu_{c}$, where $\nu_{c}$ is the frequency of the atom?!

Electronic structure in a solid is different from that of the atoms. You can't link an emitted electron to any atom, but instead to the collective.

And even if the solid consisted of a single atom, the conclusion would not be that this atom must have levels $(n+1)h\nu_{c}$ and also not that the atom has absorbed the enery $\hbar{\nu}$ because at least part of the energy has gone to the ejeced electron.

@Jack With that extra provision (which you could add to the question if you wish) you could still not conclude that the atom must have levels $(n+1)h\nu_{c}$, only two of them are $h\nu_{c}$ apart, but de distances between the others levels can be different. Atoms do not have equidistant levels!
